# jQuery validator still flags up error after it's fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the [jQuery validator plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) on [this signup form](http://comfyshoulderrest.com/shopaholic/).

The problem I'm having is that if I focus out of the input box and it contains an error (invalid email or empty box) and I then go on to fill out the form properly, whatever the last error was doesn't disappear.

So, for example, if I miss out the '@' when filling in my email address and get the "Please enter a valid email address." error, this error persists even after I put the '@' in.

Here's the code I'm using to initialise:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#form').validate(
    {
        rules:
        {
            email:
            {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element)
        {
            $('#hidden').html(error);
        }
    });
});
```

And here's my form:

```
<form id="form" role="form" class="form-inline" method="POST">
    <p id="p">Get notified when Shopaholic launches</p>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter email">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Notify me</button>
</form>
<div type="hidden" id="hidden" class="p"></div>
```

**UPDATE**

Following Sparky's answer, the code that worked was this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#form').validate(
    {
        rules:
        {
            email:
            {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        errorLabelContainer: "#hidden",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element)
        {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is breaking the plugin...

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    $('#hidden').html(error);
}
```

`error` is an object, not HTML, and `element` is the input object that triggered the error.

The default function is: `error.insertAfter(element)`

Whatever the custom function, you really should use `error` and `element` objects as the plugin automatically toggles the visibility of its `error` object.

There are other options you can use if you don't want the messages inside of a `label` or if you want all messages to be placed inside another container.

See all options here:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: Hey Sparky - just an FYI, they added hidden anchors to the validate options, so you can make a link [like this](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#errorplacement) now!

Comment: @Ryley, finally!  Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
    $('#form').validate(
    {
      rules:
      {
        email:
        {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        email: "Please enter a valid email address."
    }
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LXnbs/)